# Estou tentando substituir as letras por números e depois somá-los

Tags: php

```
 $nome = "Johnny Henrique da Silva";
$vogais = array('A','E','I','O','U');
$subCarVogais = array('a' => '1','e' => '5','i' => '1','o' => '7','u' => '6');

function funSomaVetor($v) { 
  for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($v); $i++) { 
    $soma = $soma + $v[$i]; } return $soma; 
  }

$resultado = funSomaVetor($subCarVogais); echo "Resultado $resultado";
```

Comment: Já tentou fazer um `if`? E o que seria a variável `$result` que não está definida? E por que fez um `print` no meio do `<select>`?

Answer (score 0):

Com `str_pad` você pode encher uma string com os valores passados até atingir o tamanho desejado:

```
str_pad($input, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

os argumentos são:

string de entrada, quantidade de caracteres, valor que será usado para preencher, direção do preenchimento (`STR_PAD_RIGHT`, `STR_PAD_LEFT`, `STR_PAD_BOTH`),

> string str_pad ( string $input , int $pad_length [, string $pad_string
>   [, int $pad_type ]] )
>
> https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-pad.php

Comment: boooa meu boom! isso mesmo, vlww!